# instantaneous language translator

Tags: xcode, ios5

I am developing a new application for iPhone, the app must support two languages: French and Flemish.

If i will be implementing my database and store the same data on the two language, that will be a data redundancy issues which is not the aim of the database. right?

So, i am thinking about an instantaneous translator, for example, the default language and data on the DB are on French, if the user choose the Flamand language, all the data retrieved from the database (in French) will be translated in Flamand before being shown to the user.

Is this a good way, if yes, is there a translator on iOS SDK? is it the optimal solution?

Waiting for your suggestions. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Sorry, i mean French, my bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Dr.Kameleon's answer, I'd advise you to store both languages in your database. The same content in 2 languages is different content. But I'd also advise you to have a proper, manual translation, and not use automated translation for any professional grade app.

Comment: Well, I'm totally with you. Definitely, a professional-grade app should NEVER be based on automatically-translated content; unless you want a mostly crappy user experience that is... (not to mention that most automated translators do NOT get all pairs right at the same level of accuracy : **e.g.** english-french translation has worked for me WAY much better than, let's say english->my mother tongue (where the results may almost sound ridiculous))

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try some service like Google Translator with an API publicly available?

**Hint:** *I  don't think Google's service is still open for the public (obviously because of extensive abuse, but I think Altavista had something like an alternative)*

---

**UPDATE :**

- [Google Translate API v2](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) (paid service only, as far as I know...)
- [Bing Translation API](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis) (seemingly free)

Not (personally) tested :

- [Mygengo Translation API](http://mygengo.com/api/)
- [Speaklite Translate API](http://www.speaklike.com/access-professional-translation-via-api/)
- [WebServiceX Translate API](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=63)

And an example script to access **Altavista's BabelFish** translation service :

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/64937-babelizer-api-for-simple-access-to-babelfishaltavi/

Comment: I'm really really curious why this answer has been downvoted... :/

Comment: Never mind, i have upvoted it, thanx for your relevant reply friend :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're optimizing on.  Storing the information twice isn't as bad an idea as it might at first appear.  There are many cases where it can be worthwhile to have redundant information in a database for computational efficiency, for example, and this may well be one of them.

- The major cost of storing the data in both languages is that... well, you're storing the data in both languages.  This means that you'll take about twice as much space to store your text blocks.  If you have enough text that storage space is actually an issue for you, then that's obviously a concern.  If you don't, It's really not.

On the other side, there are a few benefits to storing both.

- Accuracy.  No automatic translator is going to be as good at coming up with quality translations as a reasonably competent human translator.  Of course, if you aren't hiring a human translator, and are just depending on machine translation anyway, then that's not so much of an issue.
- Speed.  Autotranslation isn't entirely trivial in processing time for large documents.  CPU cycles spent on translation are cycles not spent on other things, and because those cycles must be spent between request and response, it'll make your latency worse regardless.  If you have plenty of CPU cycles and the text blocks you're putting out are relatively small, that's less of an issue.
- Security and Reliability.  If you are intending to use an outside service to run these translations for you, suddenly your service is dependent on that service to run, and any time you go outside for anything, you're opening up a potential security hole or two (how bad those holes are depend on how you're doing it, but they'll be there.)  Alternately, if you're intending to run the translation in-house, you have to keep a translation service up and running, which may not involve security problems, but will involve additional maintenance.

So... while it's possible that your case is one where you'll want to save it in only one language (particularly if you have a lot of text overall to deal with, it comes out in small chunks, and you don't care *all* that much about the user experience of your Flamand-speaking users) it's also quite possible that it's not.